# How to add UICollectionView as a sub view of an application keyWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, keywindow

I try to add a an `UICollectionView` as a `subview` of a `keywindow` so that this `collectionview` is visible in every `ViewController` of my application.So how can I add collection view on keywindow and how or which class is used for updating in future?

Comment: I would suggest a different approach, building a layout using a view controller with two container views, one that contains a UICollectionViewController and another that contains the rest of your app's View Controllers

Comment: Thank @BJHStudios for your suggestion.I also think about it but I end up with a problem.My rest of the app view controllers have collection views table views.When I select one of the cell of any collection view or table view from those VC I need to pass an object to my every time visible collection view because I need to update my visible collection view with related data.But how do I pass data every time to my visible collection view??Thanks .

Comment: You can do that either using the delegate pattern or through a notification with NotificationCenter

Comment: can you please share me with some example code and screen shot.I am stuck with it because I already try it but not working.The scenario is something like that.I have a tab bar with 2 tabs.both tabs have VC where the VC has tableview or collection view.If I select 1 cell of any VC's table view or collection view I just need to pass an object to the always visible collection view.